# How to force scrolling up in an 2 in one page HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the correct way of forcing HTML divs to scroll up? For example, in this html structure, I have two pages in a single HTML document:

```html
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<script>
  function show(shown, hidden) {
    document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';

    return false;
  }
</script>



<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2>Part 1/2</h2>


    amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc
    mauris. Et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat.



    <br>
    <button type="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"> Next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->




  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Part 2/2</h2>


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis.
    Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis.
    Eros donec ac odio tempor. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius
    morbi enim nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque
    vitae ultricies. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed.
    Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. In ante metus dictum at. Vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra
    sit. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Neque sodales
    ut etiam sit amet. A cras semper auctor neque. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Scelerisque eu
    ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Sed vulputate
    odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper
    sit. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.
    Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc.
  </div>
  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
</crowd-form>
```

When you click next, it takes you to the next page. However, in the second page, I would like to automatically scroll up. So far I tried to add this to the script structure:

```
document.getElementById('Part2').scrollIntoView();
```

And

```
document.getElementByClassName("Page2").scrollTop = 0
```

And

```
document.querySelector('#Page2').scrollTop = 0;
```

However, none of the above is taking me to the top of the page in part 2/2. What is the correct way of scrolling up in a two pages in one page using divs HTML?

Comment: [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) has options to align at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead off trying to scroll the content div, try resetting the scroll on the `window` so that everything will be visable;

```
function show(shown, hidden) {
    document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<script>
  function show(shown, hidden) {
    document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    
    return false;
  }
</script>



<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2>Part 1/2</h2>


    amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc
    mauris. Et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat.



    <br>
    <button type="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"> Next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->




  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Part 2/2</h2>


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis.
    Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis.
    Eros donec ac odio tempor. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius
    morbi enim nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque
    vitae ultricies. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed.
    Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. In ante metus dictum at. Vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra
    sit. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Neque sodales
    ut etiam sit amet. A cras semper auctor neque. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Scelerisque eu
    ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Sed vulputate
    odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper
    sit. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.
    Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc.
  </div>
  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
</crowd-form>
```

---

If you don't want the alert modal to be visible, instead off forcing the page to the top, you can use [`scrollIntoView(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to align `Page2` to the top:

```
function show(shown, hidden) {
    const s = document.getElementById(shown);
    s.style.display = 'block';
    s.scrollIntoView(true);
    
    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
    
    return false;
  }
```

```html
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<script>
  function show(shown, hidden) {
    const s = document.getElementById(shown);
    s.style.display = 'block';
    s.scrollIntoView(true);
    
    document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
    
    return false;
  }
</script>



<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->
  <div id="Page1">
    <h2>Part 1/2</h2>


    amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornareonsectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Eu volutpat
    Nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non
    tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam ut. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc
    mauris. Et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. At tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat.



    <br>
    <button type="button" class="d-block mr-0 ml-auto" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');"> Next</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Page number one (part 1) -->




  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Part 2/2</h2>


    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis.
    Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis.
    Eros donec ac odio tempor. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius
    morbi enim nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque
    vitae ultricies. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed.
    Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. In ante metus dictum at. Vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra
    sit. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Neque sodales
    ut etiam sit amet. A cras semper auctor neque. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris. Scelerisque eu
    ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Sed vulputate
    odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper
    sit. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo.
    Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc.
  </div>
  <!-- Page number two (part 2) -->
</crowd-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scrolling isn't happening on the `<div>`s, it's happening on the `<html>` element. This should work:

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to do what you want is by using the js `scrollIntoView` method on the element you want. you can read all about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

it has an option (block) to determine the vertical alignment of the scrolled element which accepts the following values: start, center, end, or nearest. (Defaults to start)

so you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('Part2').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
```